# Return the result of a stored function

Tags: java, sql, oracle, mybatis

We are using Oracle SQL, MyBatis and Java.

I currently try to simply execute a stored function with one `Long` parameter and a then return the result (also a `Long` value).

*DAO.java*

```
public interface ProjectDao {
    Long createProject(Long ownerId);
}
```

*DAO.xml*

```
<select id="createProject" resultType="Long" parameterType="Long" statementType="CALLABLE">
    {
        call COMPANY.PKG_PROJECT.CREATE_PROJECT(#{id})
    }   
</select>
```

I tried various ways but apparently my MyBatis knowledge ends here.

*PKG_PROJECT*

```
FUNCTION CREATE_PROJECT(p_ID IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS r_ID NUMBER;

BEGIN
    DECLARE boolOwnerFound NUMBER := 0;
    r_ID NUMBER := NULL;
    BEGIN
      -- Workaround for "IF EXISTS"
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO boolOwnerFound FROM owner o WHERE o.id = p_ID AND rownum <= 1;
      IF boolOwnerFound = 1 THEN
        BEGIN
          INSERT INTO 
            project (owner_id) 
          VALUES 
            (p_ID) 
          RETURNING 
            project.id INTO r_ID;
        END;
      END IF;
      RETURN r_ID;
    END;

END CREATE_PROJECT;
```

I want to create a project by a given owner id (if that owner exists) and then return the id of the newly generated project.

Comment: Functions are generally selected, not executed.  Can you selet the function using oracle?

Comment: Wheres the function? Whats the problem?

Comment: On an aside, why are you using `LONG`s? That's a very old, deprecated datatype. You should be using `CLOB`s instead. (I realise that if you have no control over the Oracle stored proc, you probably won't be able to do anything about it, but maybe if you could switch to a CLOB that would help solve your issue?)

Comment: I tried it with "SELECT COMPANY.PKG_PROJECT.CREATE_PROJECT(123) FROM dual;" and it gave me an error message 'cannot perform a DML operation inside a query'. I will edit my question and post the function code in there.

Comment: Not sure about oracle, but at least one other db engine does not allow you to write data in functions.  Maybe that should be a stored procedure.

Comment: This might be it, but the problem is that procedures doesn't allow to return a value, functions do.

Comment: Look up OUT parameters for a procedure.

Comment: That seems to solve my problem, I'll have a look at it. I think that I was just watching on the wrong problem. Thanks. If it indeed solves my problem i'll post the final solution here.

Comment: A function can write data (insert/update/delete), but if it does it can only be called in a PL/SQL context - which you are almost doing with your `call`, but you don't seem to have anywhere for the return value to go. You'll get an error if you try to call a function from SQL, i.e. as part of a select, if that function tries to do any DML.

Comment: Is there any way to tell MyBatis to return the value the function returned? I now solved my problem with a procedure and out parameters, but I'm curious how to do it with a function instead of a procedure, because that way I can save myself from creating DVO's for every procedure I want to call.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in a function then you should make it an autonomous transaction. The structure of such function would be something along these lines.

```
create or replace function...
pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  ...
    insert
  ...
  commit;
  return id;
exception
  when others then rollback;
  raise;
  -- or return null value?
end;
```

Drawback is that the commit is out of your hands. Once the function is called, the data is committed.

Comment: Sorry, for not daring to try this out, I'm just a Java/C# dev trying to do some SQL magic because our SQL guy has been sick for days and your solution is clearly out of my bounds of sql capability. Altough it might work.

Answer (score 0):

After having a look at `out parameters` as the comment of ruudvan suggested I've been able to come up with a solution/workaround.

*DAO.java*

```
public interface ProjectDao {
    void createProject(DVOCreateProject dvo);
}
```

*DVOCreateProject.java*

```
public class DVOCreateproject {
    private long ownerID;
    private long projectID;

    ... getter & setter ...
}
```

*DAO.xml*

```
<select id="createProject" parameterType="company.project.DVOCreateProject" statementType="CALLABLE">
  {
    call COMPANY.PKG_PROJECT.CREATE_PROJECT (
        #{ownerId,   mode=IN,  jdbcType=NUMERIC},
        #{projectId, mode=OUT, jdbcType=NUMERIC}
        )
  }   
</select>
```

*PKG_PROJECT*

```
  PROCEDURE CREATE_PROJECT(p_Owner_ID     IN  NUMBER,
                           p_Project_ID   OUT NUMBER) AS

  v_boolTaskownerFound      NUMBER;

  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO boolOwnerFound FROM owner o WHERE o.id = p_Owner_ID AND rownum <= 1;
    IF v_boolOwnerFound = 1 THEN
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO
          project (owner_id)
        VALUES
          (p_Owner_ID)
        RETURNING
          project.id INTO p_Project_ID;
      END;
    ELSE
      p_Project_ID := NULL;
    END IF;
  END CREATE_PROJECT;
```

First the DVO is filled with the owners id, then the DAO is called with the DVO as parameter and after the call, the DVO contains the value for the newly created project.